# Update a table with data from another table

Tags: mysql, update

I have a Wordpress table in which I want to take the user_email from **Table2** and import it to contact_email on **Table1** one based off of the user_login. user_login and user_id equal the same value. Nothing I have tried has worked. Any thoughts?

### Table1

```
  user_id|contact_email |contact_name
 =======================================
 123     |test@test.com |deft
 124     |test3@test.com|deft3
```

### Table2 (User table)

```
 user_login|user_email     |display_name
 =======================================
 123       |test@test.com  |deft
 124       |test3@test.com |deft3
```

I have tried:

```
        UPDATE Table1
        SET contact_email = (SELECT Table2.user_email
                 FROM Table2
                 WHERE Table2.user_login = user_id )
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT Table2.user_email
                 FROM Table2
                 WHERE Table2.user_login = user_id );
```

Comment: Your query seems correct. What problem did you face?

Answer (score 0):

You can use next syntax:

```
update tbl1
join   tbl2
on     tbl1.user_id = tbl2.user_login
set    tbl1.contact_email = tbl2.user_email;
```

> ```
> select * from tbl1;
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | contact_email  | contact_name
> ------: | :------------- | :-----------
>     123 | test@test.com  | deft        
>     124 | test3@test.com | deft3
> ```

<kbd>*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=d70dc263f9879e1ff938761f193cafd0)*</kbd>

Comment: FYI - OP has reposted under a registered account [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/202710/); using this `UPDATE` statement evidently generated an error.

Comment: @RDFozz I've seen. Why evidently?

Comment: I'm assuming he had issues editing this post - this user is unregistered, the new one is registered. I suggested merging accounts.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. Update your table inner join the second table based on ids. Then we set the email from one table to the other where the ids are the same. Hope it helps.

```
UPDATE tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.user_login = tbl1.user_id
SET tbl1.contact_email = tbl2.user_email;
```