# Update a table with data from another table: truncated incorrect double value mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a Wordpress table in which I want to take the user_email from **Table2** and import it to contact_email on **Table1** one based off of the user_login. user_login and user_id equal the same value. Nothing I have tried has worked. Any thoughts? I receive truncated incorrect double value mysql when I run the

### Table1

```
  user_id|contact_email |contact_name
 =======================================
 123     |test@test.com |deft
 124     |test3@test.com|deft3
```

### Table2 (User table)

```
 user_login|user_email     |display_name
 =======================================
 123       |test@test.com  |deft
 124       |test3@test.com |deft3
```

I have tried:

```
 update tbl1
 join   tbl2
 on     tbl1.user_id = tbl2.user_login
 set    tbl1.contact_email = tbl2.user_email;
```

And received truncated incorrect double value mysql

and when I try:

```
 update tbl1
 join   tbl2
 on     tbl1.user_id = tbl2.user_login
 set    tbl1.contact_email = tbl2.user_email;
 select * from tbl1;
```

I get 2 queries successfully executed. 0 record(s) were affected. There should be around 2000 records affected, so I know its not right.

Comment: Please don't repost [the same question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202704/update-a-table-with-data-from-another-table); check [this link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your two accounts merged.

Comment: It may help to include your table definitions; could `user_id` and `user_login` be different data types? Also - If you ran the `UPDATE` query twice, got an error the first time, and no error the second, then something odd is going on. How many rows did the `SELECT` return?

Comment: Sorry, I was not registered for the first question..

Comment: Select returned 2 queries successfully executed. 0 record(s) were affected.

Comment: No rows returned by the `SELECT`? then, are you sure there are any rows in `tbl1`?

Comment: Yes. Here is copy paste of some content
Table 1
`ad_id| ad_contact_email| user_id
16071 wrong@hotmail.com 16071
16072 wrong@gmail.com 16072
16073 wrong@yahoo.com 16073`

Comment: `ID| user_login| user_email
16071 test1 test@hotmail.com
16072 test2 test@gmail.com
16073 test3 test@yahoo.com`

Comment: Could you have multiple DBs or servers with `tbl1`? If the error happened on a populate copy, and the successful queries on an unpopulated copy, that could explain things.

Comment: Both queries seem correct. What does `select count(*) from tbl1
 join   tbl2 on  tbl1.user_id = tbl2.user_login ;` return?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.  Update your table inner join the second table based on ids.
Then we set the email from one table to the other where the ids are the same.  Hope it helps.

```
UPDATE tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.user_login = tbl1.user_id
SET tbl1.contact_email = tbl2.user_email ;
```

Comment: Thnx for editing. I removed the redundant WHERE as well (it was the same condition as the ON).

Comment: Hi Thanks, With this one, I get Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:

Comment: Would this be because it needs to replace the contact_email value for multiple records?